# ¿Cómo dar formato a la fecha?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el formato de la fecha?

Quisiera poner la fecha actual, por ejemplo:

```
domingo 06 de noviembre de 2022 05:55:55
```

el código que estoy usando es:

```js
document.getElementById("current_date").innerHTML = Date();
```

```html
<div id="current_date"></p>
```

si se puede con ese o si tienen otro código que me ayude se los agradeceria

Comment: Pero el código que expusiste te pone la fecha actual, cual es el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con el método [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) pasándole las opciones adecuadas.

Por ejemplo:

```js
locale = 'es-ES'

objfecha = new Date();
fecha = objfecha.toLocaleString(locale, {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit'
});

document.getElementById("current_date").innerHTML = fecha;
```

```html
<div id="current_date">
</div>
```

Comment: eres el mejor @masterguru . Muchas gracias